# REST API Flow and Email Templates

Tags: rest, paypal

Business Model:
This business makes handmade specialty items from a large inventory of photo examples on the web site.  The owner does not want to bill until the item is ready to ship.

I'm sure the business model itself can keep us debating for days, but please do not question his approach as that is not really the point here.  It is simply how he wants to run his business.

Design:
I have developed a system for him which manages his transactions (no financial information) until he is ready, whereupon he selects the transactions by checking the ones he wants from a query-select-list of unprocessed orders.  I can then convert each ordered item to an HTML stream, REST objects, or whatever.  The customer should receive the invoice email and click on a button to take him to PayPal for payment.

I want to use the REST API object model to send all the required information to PayPal, describe the invoice and then send the email/invoice to the customer via the API.  It is not uncommon to have multiple items ordered at once.

Q1 - The API looks like it supports this usage but can anyone experienced with its use tell me if there is a show stopper I have not discovered yet?

Q2 - I have already developed an HTML template for this purpose.  Perhaps prematurely.  Does REST API allow for the use of templates?  I do not see how yet but hoping there is a way.

Many thanks.
2K

Answer (score 0):

After some more research and a half hour with Integration Support:

A1:  There are no show stoppers in the scenario described above.  The REST API (and PayPal) supports the usage I have in mind.  If anyone desires I will post back results in a few days after code complete and a bit of testing.

A2:  I was informed that my own HTML templates are supported but I still do not see how.  With the spirit of "Trust, but verify" I will continue with my efforts and ask for Integration Support at that point if I need it.

My cup and my Stack both overflow.  I am fortunate.

2kTech